# How to fit inline elements in a row with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to design my website and I would like to fit a text input and 3 buttons horizontally in a div. Here is my markup:

```
<div style="width: 400px">
  <input class="form-control" type="text">
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 1</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 2</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 3</a>
</div>
```

But the text input spans to the whole div's width and the buttons get pushed underneath it.

I've tried setting the text input's display mode to `inline` and `inline-block` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Try `flex` as well https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/sf46neL9/)

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Button 1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Button 2</a>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Button 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays the correct solution is to use the `flex` classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex flex-row bg-info">
  <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bg-danger">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bg-secondary">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the `class="form-control"` is responsible for the input spanning the whole width. Also you should remove the `width='400px'` style and use a bootstrap class or just make it bigger to contain the four elements.

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kezyroan/eLxyr23c/2/)

Since you are using Bootstrap 3 you should try this:

```
<div style="width: 600px">
   <div class="row">
       <input class="col-md-3" type="text">
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 1</a>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 2</a>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-default col-md-3">Button 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

See the official bootstrap 3 docs

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside a form tag like this

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <div style="width: 500px">
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
      <a class="btn" href="#">Button 1</a>
      <a class="btn" href="#">Button 2</a>
      <a class="btn" href="#">Button 3</a>
      </div>
</form>
```

Also add more width or make the button/text smaller so all 3 can fit

Answer (score 0):

Your given code works according to your description. All the three button and text field are in the same line. May be you did not link the bootstrap library properly. Here is the code with bootstrap link

```
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 400px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Button 3</a>
  </div>
</body>
```